# Why doesn't URLSession.DataTaskPublisher ever publish values?

Tags: swift, xcode11, combine

In Xcode 11 beta 5 or 6 my existing code that relied on `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher` stopped working. It seems like `DataTaskPublisher` is never publishing any values but I can't work out why.

I've tried with `.sink` and `.handleEvents` as subscribers. I've tested .sink with a `Just` publisher and confirmed it receives a value there.

I've also tried both giving the `DataTaskPublisher` a `URL` and giving it a `URLRequest`. I've tried a request to an API including an authorization header, as well as basic requests to google.com and apple.com. I've tried using `URLSession.shared` and creating a new instance of `URLSession`. I've also tried with and without `map` and `decode` operators.

I've used `XCTest` expectations to confirm that the test times out every single time, even if I give it a 4-minute timeout.

I just made a new example project and replicated the problem with the following code in the root view controller:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("view did load")

        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "http://apple.com")!)
            .handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { (sub) in
                print(sub)
            }, receiveOutput: { (response) in
                print(response)
            }, receiveCompletion: { (completion) in
                print(completion)
            }, receiveCancel: {
                print("cancel")
            }, receiveRequest: { (demand) in
                print(demand)
            })
    }
```

The project prints "view did load" but nothing else ever prints. Any ideas about where I'm going wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/combine-swift/ may have some tips. The print and catch seem useful.

Comment: @matt — the URL redirects so should be fine, but I also tried with other URLs and had the same issue with all of them, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that there are two problems with your code, firstly you only have a publisher (handleEvent returns a publisher) and secondly that publisher goes out of scope and disappears. This works although it isn't exactly elegant.

```swift
import Combine
import SwiftUI

var pub: AnyPublisher<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), URLError>? = nil
var sub: Cancellable? = nil

var data: Data? = nil
var response: URLResponse? = nil

func combineTest() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://apple.com") else {
        return
    }
    pub = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .print("Test")
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    sub = pub?.sink(
        receiveCompletion: { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .finished:
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        },
        receiveValue: { data = $0.data; response = $0.response }
    )
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(
            action: { combineTest() },
            label: { Text("Do It").font(.largeTitle) }
        )
    }
}
```

I did it in SwiftUI so that I would have less to worry about and I used 3 variables so that I could follow better. You need to use the 2 parameter sink as the publisher's error isn't Never. Finally the print() is just for test and works really well.

Comment: Saying that the publisher goes out of scope wasn't quite right. It was never in scope as it was never assigned. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for this! As I mentioned, I tried using `sink` and it still didn't work, but you did help me find the main problem, which was that I need to keep a reference to the subscriber. I had tried created a local variable for it, but I needed to create a class property for the subscriber so it wouldn't drop out of scope. Thanks very much for your help, this has been driving me nuts!

Edit: Just to be clear, keeping a reference to the subscriber in the class but *not* keeping a reference to the publisher works. So keeping a reference to the publisher seems to be optional.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't make that clear. In your original code the publisher disappeared in a puff of smoke but it is keeping the subscriber that is important. I believe that cancellable's have a cancel in their deinit's that destroys the chain. I discovered that if you have multiple subscribers then if any cancel it stops all subscribers, maybe that's what multicast is for.